# How can I select all and active button when I open the page in React though useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React app. I've listed some items on the ItemList Page. What I really want to do is to select all and activate the button. However, I couldn't do that.

When I first open the page and select all, the delete button isn't active but all items are selected.

When I navigate to another page and return to the previous page, then select all, the delete button is active.

Where is the problem? How can I fix it?

Here is the code shown below:

```
export default function ItemList() {
  const [selectAllCheckbox, setSelectAllCheckbox] = useState(false);
  const [selectedCheckbox, setSelectedCheckbox] = useState(false);
  const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const result = await response.json();
        setItems(result.items);

        setSelectAllCheckbox((prevState) => prevState || false);
      } catch (error) {
        throw(error.message);
      }
    };

   fetchData();

    return () => {
      setSelectedRows([]);
      setSelectedCheckbox(false);
    };
  }, [url]);



  useEffect(() => {
    if (checkAllRef.current) {
      checkAllRef.current.checked = selectAllCheckbox;
    }
  }, [selectAllCheckbox]);

  const handleCheckAll = () => {
    const updatedItems = items.map((item) => ({
      ...item,
      selected: !selectAllCheckbox,
    }));
    setItems(updatedItems);

    const updatedRows = !selectAllCheckbox
      ? items.map((item) => item.metadata.name)
      : [];

    setSelectedRows(updatedRows);
    setSelectAllCheckbox(!selectAllCheckbox);
  };


    const handleRowSelection = (name) => {
    const updatedItems= items.map((item) => {
      if (item.metadata.name === name) {
        return { ...item, selected: !item.selected };
      }
      return item;
    });
    setItems(updatedItems);
    setSelectedRows(
      updatedItems
        .filter((item) => item.selected)
        .map((item) => item.metadata.name)
    );
    setSelectAllCheckbox(updatedItems.every((item) => item.selected));
  };

{rest part of the code}

return (
    <>
 {rest part of the code}
 <button
        className="btn btn-danger"
        disabled={!(selectAllCheckbox || selectedRows.length > 0)}
        onClick={handleDeleteRows}
 >
    Delete
 </button>

 <input
     type="checkbox"
     className="js-check-all align-middle"
     ref={checkAllRef}
     checked={selectAllCheckbox}
     onChange={handleCheckAll}
  />
  {rest part of the code}
<>
)
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Which part of your code/effect are you expecting to "select all and active button"? You should add some logging around that line and see when it's firing.

Comment: When I first open the page and select all, the delete button isn't active but all items are selected.When I navigate to another page and return to the previous page, then select all, the delete button is active. This is my issue. @AndyRay

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the asynchronous nature of fetching data and updating the state in your ``useEffect``. When you first open the page and select all, the state is not updated immediately, and that's why the delete button remains disabled.

To address this issue, you can use the ``useEffect`` hook to update the state and set the initial selectAllCheckbox state after fetching the data. Additionally, you should update the ```useEffect`` dependencies to include selectAllCheckbox to ensure that it reflects the latest state.

Comment: @mzparacha How can I use this process in useEffect as I already defined two useEffect. Is it possible to write the solution code?